# VueJs how do i use data within an object retrieved from an endpoint?

Tags: vue.js

I am retrieving a scenario type from an endpoint which has been assigned to a specific person, the data comes back fine and in the VueJS web extension, the  tag i developed has a stored object of:

```
scenariotype:Object
   participants:Array[0]
   perspective:1
   scenarioDescription:null
   scenarioTypeId:1
   scenarioTypeName:"Time and Autonomous"
   scenarioTypesScenarios:Array[0]
   timeConstraint:true
```

The two things i want to be grabbing from this object is `timeConstraint` and `perspective`, however when I do:

```
if(this.scenariotype.timeConstraint == true)
```

it returns timeConstraint as undefined.

I'm assuming i'm misinterpreting the syntax so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

My component is as follows:

```
    var topLayer = Vue.component('top-layer', {
        props: ["scenariotype"],
        data: function () {
            return ({
                scenarios: [],
                status: "",
                showTimer: true,
                timeValue: 5
            });
        },
        methods: {
            getScenarios: function () {
                // GET /someUrl
                this.$http.get('ScenariosVue/GetScenarios').then(response => {
                    // get body data
                    this.scenarios = response.body.value;
                }, response => {
                    // error callback
                });
            },
            countdownTimer: function () {
                // Set the date we're counting down to
                var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
                    this.timeValue--;
                    if (this.timeValue <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                        this.showTimer = false;
                    }
                }.bind(this), 1000);
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getScenarios();
            if(this.scenariotype.timeConstraint == true)
            {
                this.countdownTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                this.showTimer = false
            }
        },
        template: `
            <div>
                <timer-area v-if="this.showTimer" :timeValue="this.timeValue"></timer-area>
                <question v-else v-for="question in this.scenarios" v-bind:key="question.scenarioId" :scenario="question" >
                </question> 
            </div>`
    });
```

I plan on having the if() in the created function, although not required.

Comment: Provide more code.That's seems like async stuff issue.

Comment: @BelminBedak edit as above

Comment: And please add part where you do this check `if(this.scenariotype.timeConstraint == true)`

Comment: @BelminBedak see edit

Comment: Well the thing you could do is maybe set `v-if` directive on the element where you are passing `scenariotype` prop.Something like `v-if="scenariotype"`.

Comment: That wouldn't work as I have specific properties within scenarioType i need to set a boolean value based on that field and also stop a method from running, otherwise it's a waste of processing power.

Comment: `watch` scenariotype and deal with it there rather than in `created`